# Query search to _Layouts directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within SharePoint 2013 - I was able to create a query for a search that allows me to find pages in my current site collection:

```
{searchTerms} Path:https://my-site/
```

Through this same search tool, is it possible to query for custom .net pages that live under my _layouts directory as well?  Something like this

```
{searchTerms} Path:https://my-site/_layouts/customfolder/
```

I am having trouble getting any results when I attempt to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, SharePoint search only index content that lives in the content database (or external content sources). The layouts folder is not stored in a content database, but on disk of the SharePoint servers.

Comment: Undersyood. But what if I know what the exact links are...is there was way I can include custom links in the search result process through SharePoint, if I know what that link should be?

Comment: I have 20 unique links coming out of the layouts directory that I know of.

Comment: @robert if you tell SharePoint to index SharePoint pages as html and not as sharepoint pages with a crawl rule might _layouts pages be indexed?

Comment: Maybe you could somehow make your own external content sources pointing to these pages, but I doubt it would actually work. What type of information is there on these pages? It somehow feels like you are using the layouts folder to store stuff that is not meant to be stored there